# How to install openforti vpn on a vanilla raspberry PI with raspian image?

Tags: vpn

Someone managed to get openfortivpn installed and working on a Raspberry PI with vanilla Raspian image? It seems it should be supported but all I get with

```
apt-get install openfortivpn
```

is that "the package has no versions available but is cited by another package"

The raspberry device is PI3 B+

and the `uname -a` command report

`Linux raspberrypi 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`

The available package would be 1.8.1 but it has unsatisfied dependency libc6 >= 2.28 while the Raspian has 2.24-11+deb9u4

I'm thinking to build from sources but having an official version would be highly preferred

-- UPDATE --
Thanks to answers below I've double checked and found that I'm still using Raspian 9 instead of 10 I'm now upgrading to 10 to check if this solve the issue

-- UPDATE 2 --
Ok, upgrading to Raspian 10 solved the issue.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention the Raspbian version, however, I imagine it's the latest one and if you are using any version before Buster, suggest upgrade to Buster.

However, follow procedure:

```
wget http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/o/openfortivpn/openfortivpn_1.10.0-1_armhf.deb  

dpkg -i openfortivpn_1.10.0-1_armhf.deb
```

Comment: You are right the version is the latest one, I've found that package already but it seems it cannot be installed due to incompatible libraries

Comment: @FabioFrumento Of course, can be. Which model of rpi? And, which package/lib is not compatible?

Comment: Ok, I'll update the question to include details so people have not to dig into comments

Comment: I think this answer mostly pointed me to the real problem so I'll check it as the solution

Comment: @FabioFrumento Good news. And, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The command you cited in your answer should work. Make sure your Internet connection works fine and `sudo apt-get update` completes without errors.